# Uploading a dataset to OpenML using the GUI/Python and the API

Tags: python, upload, dataset, http-status-code-503, openml

I've been facing issues trying to upload a dataset to OpenML both via the website's GUI and their Python API.

#### Using the GUI:

- I visited the [OpenML: upload-dataset](https://www.openml.org/auth/upload-dataset) link.
- After clicking on "Upload dataset", I received a message stating "Your dataset is uploading...you can edit it via dashboard later and share it with public."
- However, it's been months and I haven't received any notification, and my dataset is not visible in "my datasets" section.

I can't post images as my reputation stinks, but happy to provide them on request.

#### Using the API with Python:

I tried uploading using a Jupyter notebook and received a timeout error.

```py
from openml.datasets.functions import create_dataset
```

The error was:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'))
```

Dataset info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 804056 entries, 0 to 804055
Data columns (total 19 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count   Dtype   
---  ------               --------------   -----   
 0   Store                804056 non-null  category
 1   DayOfWeek            804056 non-null  category
 2   Promo                804056 non-null  category
 3   StateHoliday         804056 non-null  category
 4   SchoolHoliday        804056 non-null  category
 5   StoreType            804056 non-null  category
 6   Assortment           804056 non-null  category
 7   CompetitionDistance  804056 non-null  float64 
 8   Promo2SinceWeek      804056 non-null  float64 
 9   Promo2SinceYear      804056 non-null  float64 
 10  Year                 804056 non-null  int64   
 11  Month                804056 non-null  int64   
 12  Day                  804056 non-null  int64   
 13  WeekOfYear           804056 non-null  int64   
 14  CompetitionOpen      804056 non-null  float64 
 15  PromoOpen            804056 non-null  float64 
 16  IsPromoMonth         804056 non-null  category
 17  Sales                804056 non-null  bool    
 18  Set                  804056 non-null  category
dtypes: bool(1), category(9), float64(5), int64(4)
memory usage: 63.7 MB
```

#### Update:

On a later attempt, the dataset seemed to upload correctly, but I can't access it via the provided link. The [link](https://www.openml.org/d/45646) returns a 503 error.

Would anyone know why this might be happening or how to resolve this?

Comment: After uploading, I've tried to add a task, but the frontend seems to be broken: 

https://www.openml.org/auth/upload-task